# Flickering edges problem in Unity - Virtual Reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, antialiasing

The objects edges are flickering in virtual reality.

Below is the .GIF image of the flickering objects:

[image]

and this is a video of the flickering since the .GIF image isn't very clear: https://filebin.net/55j1998vpquxu10b/Unity_2019.1.5f1_Personal_-_003_Controller_SimplePointer.unity_-_Test_Build_-_PC,_Mac___Linux_Standalone__DX11__2019-10-06_10-17-52__online-video-cutter.com_.mp4?t=36ht1s8g

And the flickering is even worse when I wear the VR headset.

I tried both versions of Post Processing in Unity and tried all options of Anti-Aliasing which are **"FXAA, SMAA, TAA"**

**FXAA** showed the best results but the flickering was still there as shown in the .GIF image and the video above.

I also played with Unity project settings. For example, setting the **Anti-Aliasing** option to **"8x Multi Sampling"** inside the quality tab.

Nothing seems to solve this issue.

Any ideas on what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MipMap enabled on your textures ? it seems like a Mipmap problem

[MipMap Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LITIW.png)

**[EDIT]** it seems like i cant post pictures yet , the link takes to the Generate MipMap box in Texture Settings

Comment: Yes, I have it enabled